# Running Android apps on a Linux platform

Tags: android, linux, system

We're developing a Client-server system for Android apps, in which the server should be a Linux machine.

Of course we're using VMs, but that's only as good as a real mobile device. Since we're looking at improving speed, we'd like to run those apps on a Linux machine.

Can any member give a broad idea on how to run Android apps on a Linux platform ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `dex2jar` to convert an APK file to a JAR and then you need `IcedRobot` to run the Android stack above `OpenJDK`. Maybe I will try to emulate `AndroidGL` with `JOGL 2.0` (it supports both `OpenGL` and `OpenGL-ES`). Keep in mind that it is not trivial.

The emulator of `Android SDK` is quite slow but you just have to enter adb install my_file.apk to install your application.

You can run android-x86 in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Comment: It's insane that this is such a difficult thing to do, when it really should be quite easy to use a Java-based Linux system on another Java-based Linux system...